# Strange behavior of eval() in global context and in function context. IE9 & IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, jscript

I have call eval() function in global context with such code:

```
eval( (new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")).OpenTextFile("/BaseScripts/sft.js", 1).ReadAll(),  );
```

After that all local variables, function, objects that in "sft.js" script file will be added to my global context. But if same call of eval to do in local function:

```
function run_eval(path) {
   eval( (new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")).OpenTextFile(path, 1).ReadAll(),  );
}

run_eval("/BaseScripts/sft.js");
```

local variables, function, objects that in "sft.js" script file will NOT be added to my global context. Why ? According to the documentation both calls are with *this* established to the global object. Why only first call adds variables from "sft.js" script file to global object? Do not save the situation, and explicitly call of `run_eval()` in a global context:

```
   run_eval.call(this, "/BaseScripts/sft.js");
   //or
   run_eval.call(RuntimeObject(), "/BaseScripts/sft.js");
```

Both calls are equ by result to `run_eval("/BaseScripts/sft.js");`.
Any comments are welcome?

Answer (score 1):

Given this library (lib1.js):

```
// no "var" variables go into the GLOBAL OBJECT/SCOPE
goLib1 = {'name' : 'lib1', 'version' : '0.01', 'check' : function() {return goRoot === this;}};

// functions go into the CURRENT OBJECT/SCOPE
function f1() {
  return "f1";
}

function f2() {
  return "f2";
}
```

, this main script (main.js):

```
// globals (no "var" + prefix to leave no room for doubt
goFS  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
goRoot = this;
goAct = "TopLevelEval";
//goAct = "EvalInFunction";

// should be variadic
function print(x) {
  WScript.Echo(x);
}

// 'import' a library/module; hint wrt 'export'
function loadLib(lib) {
  function flocal() {
    return "I'm a local function in function loadLib()";
  }
  eval(goFS.OpenTextfile(lib).ReadAll());
  print("in loadLib: f(1) => " + f1() + " f2() => " + f2());
  print("flocal() = " + flocal());
  print("goRoot === this: " + (goRoot === this));
  // 'export' function(s)
  //this.f1 = f1;
  goRoot.f1 = f1;
}

print(goAct);
if (goAct == "TopLevelEval") {
  eval(goFS.OpenTextfile(".\\lib1.js").ReadAll());
} else {
  loadLib(".\\lib1.js");
}

print("loaded library " + goLib1.name + " v. " + goLib1.version + " 'goRoot === this'-check: " + goLib1.check() + 

")");
print("typeof f1: " + (typeof f1));
print("typeof f2: " + (typeof f2));
print("typeof flocal: " + (typeof flocal));
```

, output "TopLevelEval":

```
TopLevelEval
loaded library lib1 v. 0.01 'goRoot === this'-check: false)
typeof f1: function
typeof f2: function
typeof flocal: undefined
```

, and output "EvalInFunction":

```
EvalInFunction
in loadLib: f(1) => f1 f2() => f2
flocal() = I'm a local function in function loadLib()
goRoot === this: true
loaded library lib1 v. 0.01 'goRoot === this'-check: false)
typeof f1: function
typeof f2: undefined
typeof flocal: undefined
```

we have the evidence for

- You are correct - the "this" in a function is the 'global this', while the "this" in a method isn't. So loadLib() has access to the global context
- Conceptually, eval is like having typed in the code by hand instead of the function call.
- By writing/evaluating `goLib1 = {'name' : 'lib1', ...` (in)directly in loadLib(), you change the global context, because the meaning of the `var` which isn't there (obviously a case for linguists, philosophers, or shrinks) is "please put this variable into this".
- By writing/evaluating `function f1() { ...` (in)directly in loadLib(), you do the same as by writing `function flocal() { ...` - you define a function local to loadLib(), which shouldn't be (and isn't) visible out of loadLib()'s scope.
- If you want to make functions from the library accessible from the import function's 'outside', you can use an assignment like `this.f1 = f1;` - all this, because the is no 'local' keyword in J(ava)script, that you could drop to make functions global.
- or vice versa.